# Is there a way to activate only one particular neuron out of several neurons in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a design that would look something like this:
[image]

Right now, I am trying using the following code but what I need is the output of the second hidden layer in the 15th position of the next layer. In my case, it is being added to the 31st position using this code.

```
inputs = Input(shape=(30,), name='first_input')
hn = Dense(4, activation='relu')(inputs)
output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hn)

first_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

second_input = Input(shape=(30,), name='second_input')

from_first_model = first_model.output

merge_layer = concatenate([second_input, from_first_model ])
hn = Dense(4, activation="relu")(merge_layer)
dnn_op_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hn)
  
model_b = Model(inputs=[second_input, first_model.input], outputs=dnn_op_layer)
```

Comment: You have the right idea in your code, you would use concatenate to form the third hidden layer. Not clear what the problem is. 'does not seem to gvie what you expect' what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Taw I edited that line and explained the problem. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - slicing the tensor into the two parts and then concatenating the two parts with the output from the second hidden layer.

```
test = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(30), dtype=tf.float32)
test2 = tf.convert_to_tensor([100], dtype=tf.float32)
# create layer 3 as desired
temp, temp2 = test[:15], test[15:]
layer3 = tf.concat([temp, test2, temp2], axis=0)
```

edit - The error you were getting might have been from using the functional api. Additionally the previous example assumes the input has a shape (30,) when really the input should have a shape like (1, 30) to be consistent with tensorflow.

```
class model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.hidden4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')
        self.hidden5 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.hidden1(inputs)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        temp, temp2 = inputs[:,:15], inputs[:,15:]
        layer3 = tf.concat([temp, x, temp2], axis=1)
        x = self.hidden4(layer3)
        x = self.hidden5(x)
        return x

# test
mymodel = model()
inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(1,30), dtype=tf.float32)
mymodel(inputs)
```

Comment: Doing this gives me an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'".